# Python - Passing params to base class inheriting from TestCase

Tags: python, selenium, unit-testing, webdriver, testcase

I have some code which I'm using to run some selenium tests using Python.

I have created a base class which inherits from TestCase, which all works fine.
However, I want to be able to access a config object passed into the base class so I can reference the chromedriver executable path & whether I run the tests headless.

```
class TestBase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        is_headless = bool(distutils.util.strtobool(self.config.get("CHROMEDRIVER", "headless_enabled")))
        if is_headless:
            chrome_options.headless = True
        else:
            chrome_options.headless = False

        executable = self.config.get("CHROMEDRIVER", "executable_path")
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable, options=chrome_options)


class TestWebSite(TestBase):

    def setUp(self):
        root_dir = os.path.abspath('../../')
        self.config = ConfigLoader(root_dir + '/resources/config.ini').config
        super().setUp()

    def test_tc001_test_page_loads(self):
        pass


class ConfigLoader:
    def __init__(self, config_file):
        self.config = configparser.ConfigParser()
        if os.path.exists(config_file):
            self.config.read(config_file)
        else:
            raise SystemExit('Could not find config file to load.')
```

I'm defining self.config within the TestWebSite class, which works, although when I review in PyCharm is flags with the following warning: *unresolved attribute reference 'config' for class 'TestBase'*, unassumingly because I'm not passing in via a constructor.

What's the best way of resolving this?

I could move the config loading into the base class, but prefer to have this at the test case level.

Comment: Make `config`  a property that returns an empty dict in the base class, and overwrite it in the derived class to get it from the parser. In this case, you won't need to implement `setUp` in `TestWebSite`.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen - Thanks, forgive me, but wouldn't I need to create a constructor in the base class to be able to do this? Doing so cause problems when running the test as it tries to call a constructor in unittest.TestCase with the wrong parameters.

Comment: Well, no, why would you need a constructor?

Comment: The easiest way is just to define it in the base `setUp` and call `super.setUp` _before_ reading the config.